# Check for variable with javascript promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two variables where certain values needs to be fulfilled and then call a function. One of the variables get set from an `onComplete` call after an js-animation is finished. The other is called once a video-file is completed preloading. My problem is that I don't know which one that will be called first. Therefore I would like to check so that both values are fulfilled with a promise.
They both get their values set in two different callback functions.
I have this but I don't understand how to use the callbacks with Promise.

```
// Callback 1:
function nextSlide(event){
   finishedAnim = true;
};

// Callback 2:
function handleNextFileComplete(event) {         
   nextVideoEl.src = nextVideo;
   nextfileLoaded = "complete";
};

Promise.all([

]).then(() => {
   slider.next();
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to await both callbacks being executed or determine which callback is executed first?

Comment: Would help to show  a little more context how these would be used

Comment: You are right in regard to use promises. But they will be returned from async functions, functions who call *callbacks*. Please post code which calls callbacks.

Comment: I'm want to await both callbacks beeing executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be using promises instead of control variables. Let's say you have a function to start the animation and other to start loading the video file.

```
function startAnimation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // Start the animation and pass the onAnimationCompleted callback
         function onAnimationCompleted(event) {
             resolve();
         }
    });
}

function startLoadingVideo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // Start loading the video and pass the onVideoLoaded callback
         function onVideoLoaded(event) {
              resolve();
         }
    });
}
```

Now you can call both functions and use the function `Promise.all()` to handle the promises. The calling method would be something like:

```
let animationPromise = startAnimation();
let videoPromise = startLoadingVideo();

Promise.all([animationPromise, videoPromise])
    .then(() => slider.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that this beacame kind of complex situation.
First I have timer with this code:

```
TweenMax.delayedCall(7.3, delayCallComplete);
function delayCallComplete(event){
        finished = true;
    };
```

Then I have preloading of video with this code:

```
function loadNextVideo() {
            var preloadNext = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
            preloadNext.addEventListener("fileload", handleNextFileComplete);
            preloadNext.loadFile(nextVideo);
        };
function handleNextFileComplete(event) {         
nextVideoEl.src = nextVideo; 
nextfileLoaded = "complete";                        
        };
```

I want to check that both of these cases has happened before calling a function containing  slider.next();.